# Firefox extension is unhappy with static innerHtml

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I submitted a Firefox extension which uses `innerHtml` on content-script.js. The html content is hardcoded, multilevel nested `div` and `span` tags with `id` `class`...properties, no `script` or `a` tag. Actual info is filled in later code.

```
                const myHtml = `..........`;
                let elm = document.createElement('div');
                elm.id = 'injectedWrapper';
                elm.innerHTML = myHtml;
```

However AMO still complains for the innerHtml, even it's from `const`.

```
Due to both security and performance concerns, this may not be set using dynamic values which have not been adequately sanitized.
```

I read the [guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Sanitizer_API) but seems that Firefox still has limited support as of today. I don't want to add extra js, as it's the content script, the worst would be lots of `createElement` but the whole thing just make no sense.

So anyway to sanitize the html content to make Firefox happy?

Comment: well, we can't see the *actual* html, so how can we say

Comment: You may not want to add additional JS but probably the simplest solution to resolve this is to use [the DOM Purify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Safely_inserting_external_content_into_a_page#html_sanitization) library. There are some additional discussions I've found [here](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/safe-insertadjacenthtml-with-user-input-or-i-should-avoid-it-anyway/57737) and [here](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/safe-insertadjacenthtml-with-user-input-or-i-should-avoid-it-anyway/57737) which you may find useful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, finally got it. Here is an update for future reference.

The actual verification is done through [addons-linter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/addons-linter) and seems that it's not smart enough to analyze the code.

This will fail:

```
const myHtml = '<div></div>';
elm.innerHtml = myHtml;
```

And these will work.

```
elm.innerHtml = '<div></div>'
elm.innerHtml = '<div>'+'</div>'
elm.innerHtml = `<div>
                 </div>`
```